# Attaching IntellijIDEA debugger to remote JVM in CLI mode

Tags: linux, shell, debugging, intellij-idea, jvm

I can attach the IntelliJIDEA debugger to a remote JVM and can log needed messages. Is it possible to do the same from the Linux shell? I wanted to automate this process from the shell to get results.

Comment: Use [`jdb`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html)

Comment: The debugger is really for ad hoc investigations, if you want to log certain data, I suggest you change the problem to log what you need.